# how last->next = temp works?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

This is the code for displaying a linked list from a udemy tutorial here we will take an array and store those values in a linked list. I didn't understand how the code works. in the below code where we are storing the address of the next node how last->next=temp; works where I didn't create a last node like last=new node; I only created the last pointer. I didn't get it can someone explain to me how it's working

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
 
int main() {
 
    int A[] = {3, 5, 7, 10, 15};
 
    Node* head = new Node;
 
    Node* temp;
    Node* last;
 
    head->data = A[0];
    head->next = nullptr;
    last = head;
 
    // Create a Linked List
    for (int i=1; i<sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]); i++){
 
        // Create a temporary Node
        temp = new Node;
 
        // Populate temporary Node
        temp->data = A[i];
        temp->next = nullptr;
 
        // last's next is pointing to temp
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
 
    // Display Linked List
    Node* p = head;
 
    while (p != nullptr){
        cout << p->data << " -> " << flush;
        p = p->next;
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't understand how the code works, the first thing you can do: step through it with the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to figure out pointers is to draw boxes and arrows with pen(cil) and paper.

Here is a (sad) ASCII rendition of what happens:

```
head->data = A[0];
head->next = nullptr;
last = head;
```

`head` points to a newly created node, and `last` points to the same place as `head`:

```
   head
    |
    v
+------+------+    
| data | next |
|      |(null)|
|      |      |
+------+------+
   ^
   |
  last
```

Next,

```
// Create a temporary Node
temp = new Node;

// Populate temporary Node
temp->data = A[i];
temp->next = nullptr;
```

looks like this:

```
   head                 temp
    |                    |
    v                    v
+------+------+       +------+------+  
| data | next |       | data | next |
|      |(null)|       |      |(null)|
|      |      |       |      |      |
+------+------+       +------+------+
   ^
   |
  last
```

Then

```
last->next = temp;
```

changes the `next` member of the node `last` points to (in the first iteration, this is the same node as `head` points to):

```
   head                 temp
    |                    |
    v                    v
+------+------+       +------+------+  
| data | next |       | data | next |
|      |   ---------->|      |(null)|
|      |      |       |      |      |
+------+------+       +------+------+
   ^
   |
  last
```

And, lastly, you make `last` point to the most recently created node:

```
last = temp;
```

which gives

```
   head                 temp
    |                    |
    v                    v
+------+------+       +------+------+  
| data | next |       | data | next |
|      |   ---------->|      |(null)|
|      |      |       |      |      |
+------+------+       +------+------+
                         ^
                         |
                        last
```

and then you repeat the loop from there.

Comment: excellent thanks a lot bro for this much detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

You have already initialized the variable last as head using `last = head` just before the for loop. This is done to ensure the original head does not get modified while adding other nodes to the list. In each iteration, the last node is used to keep track of the last node in the linked list so that every new node gets added to the end of the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

> in the below code where we are storing the address of the next node how last->next=temp; works where I didn't create a last node like last=new node; I only created the last pointer.

`last` is always just a pointer. It starts out equal to `head`, which is a pointer to the first node. In your loop, you create a new node that `temp` points to, and then you set the `next` field of the node to which `last` currently points to `temp`, and then you change `last` so that it now points to that same node, which is the new last node.